# What is meaning of error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: angularjs

I have this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=sensorManagement
```

sensorManagement is my module name.

Any idea what the error above mean?

Comment: You have an injection error, so you probably miss some dependency.

Comment: you are injecting something which is not found ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the link you'll see:

> Module 'sensorManagement' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
>   you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

That means you did not declare the module, which you can fix like so:

```
angular.module('sensorManagement', []);
```

It's also possible that you have the problem as answered by Amo_Geismar, and you have the above multiple times (or forgot to load the js file).

To work with a module after declaring it, you leave out the array.

sensorManagement.module.js

```
angular.module('sensorManagement', []);
```

someService.service.js

```
angular.module('sensorManagement') // Notice the lack of ', []' here
    .factory('yourService', function() {
        // Code here...
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

possible causes:

1) In essence you are creating the same module more than once.
   I think you probably have this somewhere in your code multiple times:

```
angular.module('sensorManagement',[])
```

if you want to use the module do

```
angular.module('sensorManagement'). //chain whatever controller/filter/service/factory
```

2) you have forgotten to load the script where you declared the module so probably in your index.html you are missing

```
<script src="your/modules/sensorManagement.js"/>
```

which would contain your declaration:

```
angular.module('sensorManagement',[])
```

Comment: EDIT: This refers to a previous version of the question! Can #2 happen? I thought AngularJS loads everything in first, to prevent that. I've never actually tested that though, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Cool. I updated my comment so future visitors aren't confused by it. ;)